# How to get a "tag" from a string?

Tags: c#, tags

Please note that I am not English so explaining is difficult.

I need to get the HTML-Like tag from a string. Is there an official way of doing that?

I have got the first 3 letters of the string successfully but I can only use one letter within the tag.

```
string tag = command.Substring(0, 3); // Gets the first three letters (The tag)
command = command.Substring(3); // Removes the tag from the string.

if(tag == "<x>")
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

This code works fine but it limits me to using a single letter.
Am I able to use a tag such as `<hello>` in anyway?

Thank you very much.

Edit:

Sorry, there is confusion. My requirements is that I can input a string and the program will get the tag from the begging of the string. For example:
`>> <abc>This is a string`
And the program will find the tag (`<abc>`).
This is meant to be *like* HTML, but not actually related.

Again, sorry for my bad grammar and explanation.

Comment: There is a lot of information and boundaries missing here. What sort of tag, does it always stay the same, is it embed in text, or is it a html document, Does it contain styles, ect ect ect ect ect ect... You need some very concise input data, and some expected results.

Comment: Regex is recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
//Suppose that the source string is:

string src = "<Hello> The rest of the string....";

//To extract the tag <Hello> from the source string:

string tag = src.Substring(0, src.IndexOf(">") + 1);

if(tag == "<Hello>")
{
 //do some..
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect! I appreciate your help.